# Counting the number of ones in a binary matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

Consider a binary matrix $\mathbf A$ corresponding to values $0$ to $2^n-1$ where each row represents a length $n$ binary representation of a real number. For example, for $n=3$ we have

$\mathbf A=\begin{bmatrix}
     0   &  0   &  0\\
     1    & 0  &   0\\
     0   &  1  &   0\\
     1   &  1   &  0\\
     0   &  0  &   1\\
     1  &   0   &  1\\
     0   &  1  &   1\\
     1  &   1    & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$

Fot an arbitrary non-zero binary vector $\mathbf v$ of length $n$ (column vector), I can verify for any $n$ that $\mathbf A\mathbf v$ (mod $2$) has always $2^n/2$ ones and $2^n/2$ zeros. Is there a way to prove this analytically.

Comment: You mean ${2^n}/2 = 2^{n-1}$ ones and $2^{n-1}$ zeros, right? When $n=3$ then $n/2$ is not even an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prove it by induction on $n.$ Let $\mathbf A_n$ be matrix with $n$ columns and $2^n$ rows constructed in the manner of the matrix in the question
(which shows $\mathbf A_3$).

In the case $n=1,$ we have $\mathbf A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$
and there is only one possible non-zero vector, 
$\mathbf v=\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}.$
Then $\mathbf A \mathbf v$ has $1$ one and $1$ zero.

Now suppose the claim is true for $\mathbf A_n.$ We have
$$\mathbf A_{n+1} =
 \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf A_n& \begin{matrix}0\\ \vdots \\ 0\end{matrix}\\
                 \mathbf A_n &\begin{matrix}1\\ \vdots \\ 1\end{matrix}\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now let $\mathbf v$ be any vector of length $n+1.$
There are two cases.

In one case, $\mathbf v = [0 \cdots 0 1]^T,$ that is, $\mathbf v$ is a column vector in which all entries are zero except the last, which is $1.$
Then $\mathbf A_{n+1} \mathbf v$ is the last column of $\mathbf A_{n+1},$ which has equal numbers of zeros and ones.

In the other case,
$$\mathbf v = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v' \\ x\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\mathbf v'$ is a non-zero column vector of length $n$ containing zeros and ones, and $x$ is either $0$ or $1.$
Then
$$\mathbf A_{n+1}\mathbf v =
 \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf A_n\mathbf v'\\\mathbf A_n\mathbf v'\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}\begin{matrix}0\\ \vdots \\ 0\end{matrix}\\
                 \begin{matrix}x\\ \vdots \\ x\end{matrix}\end{bmatrix},$$
with $2^n$ copies of $0$ and $2^n$ copies of $x$ in the last vector.
We note that $\mathbf A_n\mathbf v'$ has equal numbers of zeros and ones,
and that in
$$\mathbf A_n\mathbf v' 
+ \begin{bmatrix}\begin{matrix}x\\ \vdots \\ x\end{matrix}\end{bmatrix}$$
the zeros of $\mathbf A_n\mathbf v'$ have become ones and the ones have become zeros,
so this vector also has equal numbers of zeros and ones.
So the first $2^n$ elements of $\mathbf A_{n+1}\mathbf v$ contain equal numbers of zeros and ones, and so do the last $2^n$ elements of $\mathbf A_{n+1}\mathbf v$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think that's quite right because $v = \vec 0$ will produce all zeros. Other than that edge case it should work.

You can think of $v$ as a mask over the columns of $A$ (for example, $v = [0,1,1]^T$ would select the second and third columns). Then $Av$ is just counting up the number of 1's in each row of the masked $A$. Since every row with an odd number of 1's has a corresponding row with an even number of 1's (you can always just flip the value at the first selected column: [0, 1, 0] becomes [0, 0, 1] if the second and third columns are selected). Of course this flipping only works if a non-zero amount of columns are selected! The results is that the product, modulo 2, has the same number of 1's as 0's.